# CXF client works correctly in MyEclipse but gives errors in Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf, webservice-client

My CXF version is 2.6.16 and JDK's is 1.5 and Tomcat's is 5.0.

As the title says, the client can successfully invoke the service in the IDE but not in the web container. I think there could be some difference between the MyEclipse runtime environment and Tomcat's, but I don't know what it is.

I am using the `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` prototype's `create` method to create a port prototype, however it throws an exception in Tomcat.

Here is the error stack info.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.Utils.getFieldXJTA(Utils.java:269)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:357)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.begin(JAXBContextInitializer.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.walk(ServiceModelVisitor.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:325)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
```

Comment: I agree.  It looks like a classpath issue.  So please post the classpath used by MyEclipse as well as the startup log from Tomcat.

Comment: Take a look to source code of [Utils](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/a36af6323505211479c875fb9923cc6dcbc6ac95/rt/databinding/jaxb/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxb/Utils.java). Java 5 is not shipped with JAXB, so my guess is you have ommitted JAXB libraries in classpath

Comment: CXF implementation of JAXB needs to load the package of input and output classes from ClassLoader, but your ClassLoader implementation doesn't register the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I resolved this problem by myself. Hoping this experience could help someone.

I read the source code of org.apache.cxf.jaxb.Utils.getFieldXJTA(Utils.java:269) where the error stack info writen on the first line.

```
XmlJavaTypeAdapters adapters = f.getDeclaringClass().getPackage().getAnnotation(XmlJavaTypeAdapters.class);
```

As you can see, one of getDeclaringClass method or getPackage method must return null , so the exception could happen. But I don't know which one is the right one.So I edit the source code like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = f.getDeclaringClass();
Package pkg = clazz.getPackage();
XmlJavaTypeAdapters adapters = pkg.getAnnotation(XmlJavaTypeAdapters.class);
```

And replace the class file in the jar file. Finally,I found that the getPackage method returned null.Then I continued to read the java source code about the getPackage method.

I found that it's hard to let the method return null, the only reason (only my thought) could be in the classloader.

In the IDE , my code was using Java defalut classloader,but in my Tomcat was using a classloader written by someone other. And the classloader's findClass method haven't invoken a definePackage method, so the getPackage method return null.Then I edit the classloader, the problem resolved.

Thanks for the people who helped me with the grammer issues and the people who answered me.